# trigger.io - Release ipa - file for appstore

Tags: app-store, trigger.io, application-loader

I've successfully created an ipa with trigger.io but unfortunately, there is no description on how I can upload the ipa-file on Apple's appstore.

Can anyone help me please?

Thanks,

enne

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Information can be found at the iOS Dev Center - https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action

When ready for upload you utilize the Application Loader to upload your ipa-file.  Here is a PDF -

https://itunesconnect.apple.com/docs/UsingApplicationLoader.pdf